# Get jQuery dropdown to load and drop gracefully

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get this jQuery dropdown to work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/a2geG/2/

The first problem is that both .bounce-summary div elements are open by default. I'd like them to be closed by default and have included the following to achieve that, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
 .bounce-summary {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
```

The second issue is that when then first li element is clicked, the bottom one doesn't transition smoothly but seems to jump a bit as well. How can I prevent this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ll tell you what the problem is :

when you add margin to `div` then it adds to all the divs.

So when you try clicking to have the bounce effect, the resulting div will have margins on top and bottom as well as the original div which is already present.

added

```
    li{
        margin: .5em 0;
    }

    .bounce-summary{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

and removed the margin from the `div`.

fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/a2geG/12/)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `easing: 'swing'`, it makes it much smoother and just set toggle to `false` later after defining toggle. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2geG/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ol.rounded-list li").click(function () {
        $(this).find("div.bounce-summary").toggle("slide", {
            duration: 700,
            easing: 'swing',
            direction: 'up'
        });
    });
    $(this).find("div.bounce-summary").toggle(false);
});
```

### Update 1

I just added to `.rounded-list` the following css:

```
div.enumerate {
    display: block;
    margin: .5em 0;
}
```

while removing `margin: .5em 0;` from the main `div`:

Updated Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2geG/11/)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. However, I might not have explained myself well: I like the bounce effect. What bothers me is that the li element below the first one also seems to be jumping. Do you see that?

Comment: @DaniG2k, yes I see it.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent that that you'd know? It's rather annoying :\

Comment: @DaniG2k The `margin` set for the div causes the problem. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2geG/7/)

Answer (score 1):

The boxes are both expanded because you define:

```
.rounded-list {
    ...
    div {
        display: block;
    }
    ...
}
```

which takes precedence over the `display: none` defined in your `.bounce-summary`, as the aforementioned selector is more specific.

Comment: Ok this seems to have fixed the issue of hiding the blocks by default. Oddly though, it seems that no matter how I change the `.bounce-summary` class it doesn't make a differnce. For instance, if I put `background: #000;` the background color doesn't change at all. Any idea why the css won't change?

Comment: The reason is pretty much the same, another CSS seletor (again `.rounded-list div`) is more specific, and defines `#f8f8f8` as background colour. It's not always easy to see which selector will be more specific, but it's relatively easy to see what actually applies to an element through the browsers' built in debuggers. Press F12 in IE, or CTRL-SHIFT-I in Firefox/Chrome/Opera, then take a look at the *Elements* tab and find your DOM element. The *Styles*  (or similar) sub-tab will tell you what applies, and what is overridden.